# the second letter of the name justin does not capitalize why

Tags: python-3.x

the first and second letter of the name "Justin" does not capitalize. why?

```
prenom = input("Votre prenom : ") 
prenom1 = "Justin" 
for nom in prenom1: 
    if prenom1.lower() == prenom.lower(): 
        prenom1[0].upper == prenom1[0] 
        prenom1[1].upper == prenom1[1]
        print (nom)
```

it justin and not JUstin

Comment: Try [formatting your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189) so we can read it more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is by slicing your string.

```
prenom = input("Votre prenom : ")
# Votre prenom : justin

prenom_longueur = len(prenom)
sortie = ''.join(prenom[0:2].upper() + prenom[2:prenom_longueur])
print (sortie)
# output
JUstin
```